# Identity Server 4 : Is it possible to use NoSQL for Operational Store (Persisted Grants)

Tags: c#, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, identityserver4

### Is there a way to use NoSql DBs like Cosmos DB for Operational data store(Persisted Grants) of Identity server 4?

Note: Keeps in mind the problems with partitioning and indexing.

If we observe the methods of IPersistedGrantStore of IdentityServer4, we can get to know that we should be able to fetch data using 'key' and 'subjectId' individually.

***Table Storage***: I have tried and dropped the idea of using table storage  due to the following reasons:

1. Table storage is only indexed on partition key and row key (no
   secondary index). So, we need to duplicate the data to achieve
   indexing on both 'key' and 'subject id' properties. This results in
   problems with data consistency and race conditions.

***Cosmos DB SQL API***: Cosmos DB supports indexing on all properties and supports TTL (great).. but the problem is with partitioning.

2. A single logical partition has an upper limit of 10 GB of storage.
   So, we need to do partition either by using 'key' or 'subject id'.
   If 'key' is used for partition then queries with 'subject id' need
   to do a full db scan and vice versa.

   ```
   public class IPersistedGrantStor {
    Task<PersistedGrant> GetAsync(string key);
    Task<IEnumerable<PersistedGrant>> GetAllAsync(string subjectId);
    Task RemoveAsync(string key);
    Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId);
    Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId, string type);
   }
   ```

Is there a right way to partition the persistant grant store data, which avoids full db scan for both getByKey and getBySubjectID?

or Go with SQL DB ?

Comment: 1 - https://github.com/PowelAS/Powel.AzureTableStorage.IdentityServer4

Comment: 2 - You could take a look to see how they did it here: https://github.com/jnhaffey/IdentityServer4.Contrib.CosmosDB

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons !! Powel.AzureTableStorage is inefficient becuase search by 'subject id' using that repo results in full db scan.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons !! in Contrib.CosmosDB repo the entire collection is fetched for every request , which can cause someother prblms